# Sull'uso dell'espressione "il caso è che"

Tags: word-usage

Ho letto l'espressione "il caso è che" su alcuni siti web, ma non sono sicura che tale espressione sia corretta. Se è corretta, non so come si debba usare. Per esempio, se sto spiegando un incidente accaduto in un liceo, sarebbe corretto scrivere questa frase?

> Il caso è che i professori hanno dovuto chiamare un'ambulanza.

Mi aiutereste a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Ecco alcuni degli esempi che ho trovato su Internet:

> - Il caso è che Washington sta tentando di fare pressioni sulla Turchia per entrare nel territorio siriano, ma allo stesso tempo per non permettergli di portare a termine un intervento che sembri un attacco totale contro il governo del paese arabo.
> - Il caso è che perfino la costruzione della sede delle Nazioni Unite in New York fa parte di quegli stratagemmi utili.
> - Il caso è che studiandosi in dettaglio gli svenimenti presidenziali, si trovò il possibile vincolo degli stesso col sistema elettrico del cuore, quello che produrrebbe tendenze alla lipotimia e pertanto svenimenti.
> - Il caso è che piano piano e dopo aversi sentito dire di tutto, Google sta iniziando a dare nuove e utili funzionalità allo strumento parole chiave di Adwords, tra le quali la novità che ti segnalo in seguito.

**Aggiornamento:** Forse l'espressione corretta in italiano sarebbe "il fatto è che"?

Answer (score 2):

'Il caso è che' tanti costrutti che si leggono in internet sono scritti da persone che a scuola prendevano al massimo quattro in italiano.

Gli stessi esempi riportati nella domanda mostrano quanto sopra, addirittura nell'ultimo—ed è eclatante—c'è un 'dopo aversi' che doveva essere 'dopo essersi'.

Usa quindi il costrutto in discorso solo dopo che ti hanno chiesto 'Qual è il caso?'  ed evita di usarlo come forma di stile per introdurre qualsivoglia proposizione.

Comment: Penso si tratti di un'influenza dello spagnolo "el caso es que". Forse l'espressione corretta in italiano sarebbe "il fatto è che"?

Comment: @Charo 'il fatto è che' può funzionare, ma solo per replicare a qualcuno che sosteneva un'opzione diversa.

Comment: Dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fatto2/): Pleonasticamente, per introdurre con più efficacia un’affermazione o anche una semplice constatazione: *il fatto è che sono stufo d’aspettare*.

Comment: @Charo Il Treccani ha ragione, ma il contesto nel quale si introduce una proposizione con 'il fatto è che' deve essere almeno di scetticismo o di incertezza rispetto al fatto che è. Perché se uno esordisse con 'Il fatto è che' in un contesto dove nessuno dubita che quello sia il fatto sembrerebbe quantomeno un pazzo.

Answer (score 2):

Un'espressione comune (anche se non del tutto equivalente) è

> Si dà il caso che ...

che potrebbe approssimativamente corrispondere allo spagnolo "el caso es que ...".